# Parse string date to OffsetDateTime when time zone information is missing

Tags: java, datetime, jackson

I'm receiving a string time object from a third party that looks like this: `12/12/2021 3:34:30 PM`. The time zone information is missing but I know it is UTC.

I'm using Jackson to parse the csv and have been playing around with the annotations to try and get it to parse correctly. Here is what I currently have:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a", timezone = "UTC", lenient = OptBoolean.TRUE)
protected OffsetDateTime shareDate
```

which gives me the error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` from String "12/12/2021 3:34:30 PM": Failed to deserialize java.time.OffsetDateTime: (java.time.DateTimeException) Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {InstantSeconds=1639323270},ISO,UTC resolved to 2021-12-12T15:34:30 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

I can change the OffsetDateTime to LocalDateTime and it works. I would rather save it as an OffsetDateTime since I do know it is always UTC. Anyone out there know how to set the annotation to get that to work? Or is it not possible that way?